# Array don't allow minus indexing c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have the following procedure that counts the document frequency  for each entry of doctionary (freq)

```
  foreach (var termIndex in freq.Select(entry => GetTermIndex(entry.Key)))
         {                                                              
            _docFreq[i][termIndex]++;
         }
```

And also the procedure for getting term index

```
rivate int GetTermIndex(string term)
    {
        int i;
        if (_wordsIndex.TryGetValue(term, out i))
            return i;
        else
            return 0;
    }
```

Where, all terms are indexed in another dictionary (_wordsIndex).

Based on above procedures, if the entry.Key in freq not exist, then the GetTermIndex will return 0 and that will count up the _docFreq (_docFreq[i][0]) and that is the problem. 
So, how could i avoid counting when the entry.Key not exist ?? I tried to do something like

```
rivate int GetTermIndex(string term)
    {
        int i;
        if (_wordsIndex.TryGetValue(term, out i))
            return i;
        else
            return -1;
    }
```

But of course an error "Index was outside the bounds of the array" appeared, because there no index for _docFreq[i][-1].

Could any help please ?? many Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just don't count it if `termIndex` is -1:

```
foreach (var termIndex in freq.Select(entry => GetTermIndex(entry.Key)))
{
    if (termIndex >= 0)
        _docFreq[i][termIndex]++;
}
```

or using LINQ `Where`:

```
foreach (var termIndex in freq.Select(entry => GetTermIndex(entry.Key)).Where(ti => ti >= 0))
{
    _docFreq[i][termIndex]++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the value that the function returns:

```
foreach (var termIndex in freq.Select(entry => GetTermIndex(entry.Key))) {
  if (termIndex != -1) {
    _docFreq[i][termIndex]++;
  }
}
```

or:

```
foreach (var termIndex in freq.Select(entry => GetTermIndex(entry.Key)).Where(i => i != -1)) {
  _docFreq[i][termIndex]++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
  foreach (var termIndex in freq.Select(entry => GetTermIndex(entry.Key)).Where(index=>index>=0))
     {                                                              
        _docFreq[i][termIndex]++;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to skip those invalid values:

```
foreach (var termIndex in freq.Select(entry => GetTermIndex(entry.Key))).Where(x => x >= 0)
     {                                                              
        _docFreq[i][termIndex]++;
     }
```